# Protractor Timeout Test

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, sinon

I want to create an UI automated test for an Angular app using protractor, that locks the user after some amount of login attempts and unlocks it after 5 minutes of inactivity.

I dont want to wait the whole 5 minutes in order to test this feature, so I found that Sinon.js fake timers could help me out with that.
I have this Sinon code which fakes the time:

```
this.clock=sinon.useFakeTimers(new Date().getTime());
```

then with this other sentence I add the 5 minutes to the faked clock:

```
this.clock.tick(300000);
```

The time seems to be faked correctly but the test doesnt pass after doing this.
Do I need to call a $digest cycle so angular can know about that the time has changed?
If that is how can I do it with Protractor?
Or,Does anyone have a better approach in order to test this feature?